# Setup PHPUnit for netbeans and xampp

Tags: netbeans, phpunit, xampp

I'm struggling to setup PHPUnit (3.7.20) in netbeans (7.3) and xampp. When I create a new project with code under C:\xampp\htdocs, I can run a test in netbeans without problems.

However I usually use virtual hosts for my code. The code is under D:\PATH\TO.

When I run C:\xampp\php>phpunit.bat --bootstrap D:\PATH\TO\tests\bootstrap.php D
:\PATH\TO\tests\module\Application\src\MyControllerTest.php in the windows console the test executes fine.

When I try to use netbeans for the same task, the he skeleton generator works fine. But if I want to test a file I get "Perhaps an error occurred, verify in Output window." as test result. The the output window gives "Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden." ("The system cannot find the given path").

Do you know how I can fix this problem? Where can I see what's going wrong?

Comment: Hey, Are you still struggling or got your problem solved?